# Garbage collection of objects as arrays of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, garbage-collection

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) I've read a simple `delete` is not enough to free the memory allocated for an object.

I have an `Object` containing some subOjects, in the form: `MyObject[idx]['foo']`. Is there a way to free the memory used by Objects containing subObjects?

If I make a `MyObject[idx]=null` is this enough for garbage collection?

Comment: this is a big wall of text that I doubt anyone would want to read - isolate your questions and ask them one by one without all this unnecessary sugar coating

Comment: Done as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read a simple delete is not enough to free the memory allocated for an object

`delete` has nothing to do with memory management in the first place. The text you are referring to also clearly states this.

With regard to memory `MyObject[idx]=null` and `delete MyObject[idx]` have the same effect. If the object that `MyObject[idx]` has pointed to is not being referenced anywhere else then the garbage collector will eventually remove that object from memory.

Usually you won't come into a situation where you actually want to free memory. You may delete properties or remove elements from arrays when you no longer need them. But that's not the same.